tf.callbacks.EarlyStopping doesn't work properly when feeding tf.data.dataset objects to the model
I set patience=5 for it to stop training if val_loss doesn't decrease for 5 epochs straight. However, training always stop at the 5th epoch, and the best weights are set to 1st epoch even though val_loss is still decreasing.
This only happens when I feed tf.data.dataset objects to the model. When I feed numpy array to the model, it still works like I intended.
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat().batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_dataset = val_dataset.repeat().batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


early_stopping_ = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min',
    patience=5,  # Number of epochs with no improvement after which training will be stopped
    verbose=1,
    restore_best_weights=True
)


model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 50, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=20,
    steps_per_epoch = math.ceil(train_size/32),
    #batch_size=32,
    validation_data = val_dataset,
    validation_steps = math.ceil(val_size//32),
    verbose=1,
    callbacks = [early_stopping]
)```


Can you give us a (minimal) reproducible example or show us (as text) your training output? I tested it with random data as a dataset and could not reproduce your problem. Even with random data (where there is nothing really to learn) early stopping stops around epoch 15-20, and the val_loss decreases before. TF version is 2.16.1, Keras 3.3.3.
